# What's wrong with these Ant/JVM args?

Tags: java, ant, jvm-arguments

I am trying to run [JBoss TattleTale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) from an Ant buildfile. Usually I run it from the commandline like so:

```
java -Xmx512m -jar /home/myuser/jars/tattletale.jar /home/myuser/projects/lib /home/myuser/tmp/tt
```

where `/home/myuser/projects/src` is the source directory where all my JARs are, and where `/home/myuser/tmp/tt` is the output directory where I place all of TattleTale's reports.

In the Ant buildfile I am using the following:

```
<echo message="Running tattle-tale..."/>
<java fork="true" failonerror="true" jar="/home/myuser/jars/tattletale.jar">
    <arg value="Xmx512m"/>
    <arg value="/home/myuser/projects/lib"/>
    <arg value="/home/myuser/tmp/tt"/>
</java>
```

When I run this target from the commandline:

```
run-tattletale:
    [echo] Running tattle-tale...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
```

When I go to `/home/myuser/tmp/tt` I don't see any output, however the Ant output shows `SUCCESS` with no errors or warnings. Do my `<arg>`s look correct, and if not, how should I change them? If they do look correct, what can I do to debug? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Two things:

1. Try using the debug option when running Ant, and save the output into a logfile. Then look at the log file. It will show you how it is executing the Java command. That will help you figure out where the Ant `<java>` is differing from the way you run Java directly from the command line. It'll give you the ability to tweek your `<java>` task.
2. When a parameter is for the `java` command itself, you use `<jvmarg>` and not `<arg>`:

An example:

```
<echo message="Running tattle-tale..."/>
<java fork="true"
    failonerror="true"
    jar="/home/myuser/jars/tattletale.jar">
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>  <!-- Note the dash! -->
    <arg value="/home/myuser/projects/lib"/>
    <arg value="/home/myuser/tmp/tt"/>
</java>
```

Try that, and run with `ant -d | tee ant.out` if you're on Unix/Linux. On Windows, you'll have to do `ant -d > ant.out.txt` which will save the output in `ant.out.txt`, but won't display the output while `ant` is running.

Answer (score 3):

The first args is a JVM argument not a program argument so `<arg>` is the wrong syntax. For this case it's easier to use the `maxmemory` parameter of the `java` task.

So remove the first `<arg>` and put `maxmemory=512m` in the `<java>` block.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Q (+1) - but I'm still not seeing anything being generated in the output directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you see no output in target directory, it may be due to 1) there is no archive in given input directory or 2) tattletale process is failing. 
In case of failure or exception, tattletale process seems returning exit code `0` and it makes ant believe that the process execution is successful.

For debugging, I suggest you to 
ensure *given directory is correct and has java archive (jar) files* and analyze the *standard output/errors* produced by `tattletale`.

Example:

```
<echo message="Running tattle-tale..."/>
<java fork="true"
    failonerror="false" 
    errorproperty="errorproperty"
    outputproperty="outputproperty"
    jar="/home/myuser/jars/tattletale.jar">
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>  <!-- Note the dash! -->
    <arg value="/home/myuser/projects/lib"/>
    <arg value="/home/myuser/tmp/tt"/>
</java>
<echo message="stdout>> ${outputproperty}"/>
<echo message="stderr>> ${errorproperty}" />
```

Note:- `failonerror` is false temporarily for debugging purpose only.